# Woocommerce Pagination Issue for Same Price Product

Tags: wordpress, pagination, woocommerce

Suppose i inserted product category *Shirt* and for that category i added 17 products which all have the **same price**.
I display only 12 product in one page.  
My default sorting option is **high to low** by price. 
Now on page load it display 12 product (remember price is same).
If i click on second page for remaining 5 product its repeat some product from first page instead of all remaining 5.
I used some filter but it not help:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args' );
function custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {
    $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? woocommerce_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );

       if ( is_product_category( array('shirt' ) )) {
                   // exit;
                    $args['orderby'] = 'ID';
                    $args['order'] = 'DESC';
                    $args['meta_key'] = '';
      }

    return $args;
}
```

> How i can remove that repeating product from second page.
>   This issue is only arrived if all product have same price.

Comment: Some questions: where did you get this code (your source)? In your code where do you use the defined var `$orderby_value`?

Comment: No not my @LoicTheAztec but i modified as per my requirement. i think $orderby_value is only useful if u add your custom sort. i don't want to add extra sorting option

Comment: I didn't understand ??? But where have you picked up this code?

Comment: I don't think is possible to order, the way you want, without ding a custom field in products. Tell us if you find a solution